# Keep typeahead.js suggestions open when out of focus

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I'm using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) and I want to see its elements on chrome's console, but no matter what I do, the suggestions disappear.

What can I do in order to prevent this default behavior of remove elements when out of focus?